# Can I create an object from a derived class by constructing the base object with a parameter?

Tags: c++, constructor, polymorphism, copy-constructor

In other words, given a base class `shape` and a derived class `rectangle`:

```
class shape
{
public:
  enum shapeType {LINE, RECTANGLE};
  shape(shapeType type);
  shape(const shape &shp);
}

class rectangle : public shape
{
public:
  rectangle();
  rectangle(const rectangle &rec);
}
```

I'd like to know if I could create an instance of `rectangle` by calling:

```
shape *pRectangle = new shape(RECTANGLE);
```

and how could I implement the copy constructor, in order to get a new `rectangle` by calling:

```
shape *pNewRectangle = new shape(pRectangle);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short Answer: No

Long Answer:

You need a factory object/method.
You can add a static factory method to the base class the creates the appropriate object type.

```
class Shape
{
    static Shape* createShape(shapeType type)
    {
        switch (type)
        {
             case RECTANGLE:return new rectangle();
           ...
        }
    }
 };
```

#### Personal preference:

I would go with a completely different class to be the factory rather than using a static method on the base class. The reason for this is that every time you create a new Shape  class the above style forces you to re-build the Shape class each time.

So I would separator out the factory into a ShapeFactory class.

Comment: Why a class? I would simply make a factory function.

Comment: that's it, then.
And according to this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1021626/c-could-polymorphic-copy-constructors-work - I guess I also have to use a Clone method instead of the copy constructor.

Comment: In the trivialist of cases a factory function is fine. But when things get more complex and you need to split the factory call into a couple of function calls the accesability constraints are a lot easier to handle then having multiple static functions. But in this case it is just a matter of style.

Comment: When things a re more complex, if you have a class you can start using abstract factories and thus return different types of object depending on runtime configuration. So I could have a WindowShape factory and MacShapeFactory based of a simple abstract base factory. Again you can do this with functions but it just is never quite as neat.

Comment: Cloning is so Java like. It just makes me shiver.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this directly from within the constructor.  Instead, you'll need to use another approach, such as a [Factory method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern).

The problem is, when you do new shape(...), you'll always return an instance of shape - not rectangle.  If you want a "rectangle", at some point, it will need to call new rectangle(..).  A method could handle this logic for you, but not the default construction in C++.

Answer (score 0):

Calling a constructor will always give you an object of the type of the constructor.

```
new shape(...)
```

I think you want to use the factory design pattern instead, where there is a static method on shape that can create any subtype, as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

```
shape *pRectangle = new shape(RECTANGLE);
```

There is no way for you to create a derived class by constructing a base object. You have to do a new of the derived class itself.

Answer (score 0):

In C++ you can use dynamic casting to accomplish this, but erm, no, not from within the constructor. Use it as implied above in a factory method

see e.g http://www.cprogramming.com/reference/typecasting/dynamiccast.html

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that with Policy-Based design. Your code would be something like

```
shape* pRectangle = new derrivedType<rectangle>();
```

[Policy-Based Design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Policy-based_design)