# How to un-delete constructors in child classes?

Tags: c++, inheritance, struct, constructor

So in our codebase there is this struct:

```
struct NonCopyable
{
private:
    NonCopyable(const NonCopyable &) = delete;
    NonCopyable &operator=(const NonCopyable &) = delete;
};
```

and a struct that inherits from it:

```
struct Foo : NonCopyable {

}
```

Now, how can I make a struct that inherits from `Foo`, but is copyable?

Tried this, with no success:

```
struct CopyableFoo : Foo {
    CopyableFoo (const CopyableFoo &) = default;
    CopyableFoo &operator=(const CopyableFoo &) = default;
}
```

What I ultimately want to achieve is this compiles well:

```
CopyableFoo foo;
auto bar = foo; // copy works
```

Comment: What do you want that copy to do, given the prior design decision that the `Foo` part should not be copied?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A defaulted copy c'tor that is not deleted works by copying each base and member in turn. It relies on those bases copy c'tors to do the job. If one doesn't exist, it cannot choose any meaningful action to do instead.

The base class is not copyable, that's part of its invariants and you can't force a compiler to undo that. The only choice you have is to implement the copy c'tor yourself. Only the programmer can choose meaningful semantics in this case.

And the same goes for copy assignment.

Comment: Thank you so much! So I have to replace `=default` with `{}` in `CopyableFoo`? Uhm, what goes into the braces? Any slight directions would help! I am quite a newbie in C++ (2-3 weeks)

Comment: @Nurbol - I can't tell you how to implement copying. I don't have the real classes before me. I don't know how they are meant to behave, only you do. Any advice I can give based on the reduced example is likely to be wrong. As for just using braces, that won't copy anything. Like any c'tor that is just a pair of braces, it will default initialize all bases and members.

Comment: @Nurbol - I would suggest starting at this reference https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list

Answer (score 2):

### Warning: this would make all of the derived classes copyable.

@StoryTeller has already given a very nice explanation of what happens under the hood when you `= default` your copy constructor/assignment operator, so I am going to skip that part.

There is another way (other than writing `{}`,) to make your base class copy constructor/assignment operator accessible from derived class, but not outside: using `protected` member access specifier (see [access specifiers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/access)):

```cpp
struct Base {
    Base() = default;
protected:
    Base(const Base& other) = default;
    Base& operator = (const Base& other) = default;
};

struct Derived : public Base {
    Derived() = default;
    Derived(const Derived& other) = default;
    Derived& operator = (const Derived& other) = default;
};
```

Comment: @NurbolAlpysbayev Just a note. If polymorphism is involved, see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1021626/9171697

Comment: `NonCopyable` is meant to be a mixin that disables copying. If one does as you suggest, it sorta defeats the intended purpose. @NurbolAlpysbayev - You should be warned that now **all** classes that inherit from `NonCopyable` are copyable, not just the one you wanted to change.